# Data picking from different cells within sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am currently working on a warehouse datasheet and looking to capture information from it. I need help with either a formula or VBA code.

```
           A          B              C
Row 1 - product - batch number - expiry date
```

These are 3 columns from multiple within the sheet, however, the focus is on them. I am trying to find a formula or VBA code to allow me to do the following:

The word "cake" used as a product reference.

If a cell within the product column has the value "cake", return the value of the cell from the expiry date column which is on the same row as the initial cell found.

Repeat this process, but skip the previously found cell.

Currently, I tried this formula:

`=IF(A:A="Cake",C1,"")`

This is what I started with and don't have a clue after it. Whatever I search for in Google I can't adjust it to what I want. I tried Vlookup too.

To me this seems like I need a VBA code that can do that on a loop and return the values automatically for me.

I know my attempt is pathetic, but I've been searching online for 2 days with no progress. Can you suggest something? Thank you

I am expecting to have a separate sheet, from all the input sheets, collecting a list of products, their batch number and the expiry date related to them, to apply conditional formatting to be warned if a batch is due to be expired.

Comment: Show us what you tried exaactly when you tried [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1).

Comment: Would a filter work for you? If you just filter column A for the product you need, you should have all the required information right?

Comment: This is my attempt doing VLOOKUP:

=VLOOKUP("DFr67",C:C,6,FALSE), to my understanding I wrote look for "DFr67" in column C, and return the value from column 6)

Comment: The sheet is massive, I can do filters but it will require time to manually adjust it and find the information from 90 different columns. I am the only person who's working in the warehouse, so I am trying to find a way to gather all the information I need automatically and look at the important stuff at a glance.

Comment: You're only looking at `C:C` - Your key is in column C, but you want to read 6 from that? Column H? Try changing `=VLOOKUP("DFr67",C:C,6,FALSE)` to `=VLOOKUP("DFr67",C:H,6,FALSE)`

Comment: I agree with @M.Schalk that all you need is **filter**. You can apply conditional formatting to the expiry date column for all products, and use filter to show the products that contain the key word. Even with `vba`, you still need to type your key word somewhere, but only look at the results in a separate worksheet, and a potential downfall is that any conditional formatting on the new sheet could be overwritten when you started a new search, or if a new worksheet is created each time you enter a new key word, you need to manually reapply the conditional formatting. Not so much efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This would be relatively easy to do in VBA:

```
Sub returnExpirydates()

Dim strInput As String
Dim lngCount As Long, lngRow As Long
Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet

strInput = InputBox("Please enter the desired product.")

lngCount = 2
lngRow = 2

Set wsInput = Sheets("YourInputSheetName")
Set wsOutput = Sheets("YourOutputSheetName")

wsOutput.Cells.Clear
wsOutput.Rows(1).Value = wsInput.Rows(1).Value

Do While wsInput.Cells(lngCount, 1).Value <> ""
    If Cells(lngCount, 1).Value = strInput Then
        wsOutput.Rows(lngRow).Value = wsInput.Rows(lngCount).Value
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
    End If
    lngCount = lngCount + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

This might require a few tweaks to fit your file, let me know if you have follow-up questions.

Comment: This is quite helpful, I am going to look up the argument you wrote to understand it. I tried it and it worked for auto filtering rows, which is better that what I have. I'll see what I can understand and adjust. Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad to help, don't be afraid to ask for follow-up help

Comment: thank you. I've been trying to adjust the loop, and not sure I am doing it correctly because it hasn't worked. To my understanding Rows(lngRow) is defining the row to input values to, and I am trying to change it to Cells(lngRow, 1) and changing Rows(lngCount) to Cells(lngCount, 3). I think my mistake is I need to add new Dimensions to replace those variables within  wsOutput.Rows(lngRow).Value = wsInput.Rows(lngCount).Value line, then add +1 to them in line with lngRow+1. Making it specific to a cell, is that right?

Comment: @Yousef Rifai Could you edit the question and insert the changed code snippet you're describing? From your description it sounds like it should work.